# @Misc equivalent in CSL YAML

Tags: pandoc, bibtex, bibliography, csl, pandoc-citeproc

I want to migrate from my BiBTeX record:

```
@Misc{        propi-records-atletisme-en,
  author    = "Bordoy, Xavier",
  title     = "Athletics records",
  url       = "http://somenxavier.xyz/public/blog/fitxers/athletics-races.pdf",
  year = "2016"
}
```

to CSL YAML:

```
references:
- type: "Misc"
  id: "propi-records-atletisme-en"
  author:
  - family: "Bordoy"
    given: "Xavier"
  title: "Athletics records"
  issued:
     year: "2016"
  URL: "http://somenxavier.xyz/bitacola/blog/athletics-races.pdf"
```

But when I compile it to pandoc, I get:

```
Error parsing references: 'Misc' is not a valid reference type
```

So, what is equivalent to @Misc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSL has more item types than standard bibtex ([here's a full list](http://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html#appendix-iii-types)), so there's no single `@misc` equivalent, but for webpages as in your example, you'd simply use `type: "webpage"`